# Woocommerce WC()->cart->add_to_cart() is not working for visitors but works for logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, cart

I am developing the plugin where i am adding the products to cart by for loop as shown in the code

```
global $woocommerce;

for ($x = 0; $x < $_REQUEST['numberofproduct']; $x++) {
    $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand());
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 801, $quantity = 1, $variation_id = 802, $variation, $cart_item_data );
}
```

When the users are logged in it cart shows the price and quantity but the users not logged in cart empty. But sometime it works visitors too.

Can anyone help me where i am wrong?

Comment: But for other normal products add to cart button works fine both for visitors and logged in users

Comment: Is there any HTTP/HTTPS protocol mismatch between logged-in VS non-logged-in users?

Comment: Please specify if you are using any page caching as well.

Comment: No I am not using any caching plugin as well. For whole site i am using http

Comment: For normal products on pages add to cart works fine for all users whether they are visitors or logged in

Comment: So where _doesn’t_ it work then …? What are your “abnormal” products then, what’s the difference between those and the “normal” ones?

Comment: But add_to_cart() function show empty cart when user is visitor

Comment: I have added the code in plugin WC()->cart->add_to_cart( );

Comment: I would recommend trailing the error log when a product is added to the cart as a vistitor(guest)

Comment: Didn't find any error in error log

Comment: There is an answer to your question now if you still need it.

Comment: You need to initiate Woocommerce User session when it's not logged in. So you will use the following:

add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'force_non_logged_user_wc_session' );
function force_non_logged_user_wc_session(){ 
    if( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() )
       return;

    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) 
       WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true ); 
}