# Make WC_Cart add_to_cart method working for guests in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, cart

Im trying to get my code to work. Searching for hours now.
I found similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871936/woocommerce-wc-cart-add-to-cart-is-not-working-for-visitors-but-works-for). But unfortunately noone seems to find a solution.

In my custom plugin I want to add a specific item to the WC cart and redirect the user directly to the checkout. As a logged in user it works like a charm but for guests it shows a blank page on checkout (woocommerce_checkout shortcode seems to return nothing in this case). 
So I came up with a check if the cart iss till empty. Apparently it is because the "cart-page" shows "There are no items in the cart yet".

In code i check if the cart is still empty but it tells me its not!

Here is my code:

```
if(!$wooID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT wooID FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."ceb_events WHERE id = $event")) die("ERROR GETTING WOOID");

WC()->cart->empty_cart();

if(!WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $wooID, 1 )) die("CART GOT NOT UPDATED. THERE IS AN ERROR 1.");

if(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0) die("CART GOT NOT UPDATED. THERE IS AN ERROR 2."); 

//Here follows the redirect to checkout page
```

The code runs without errors. And it works 100% as a logged in user / admin. Just not as guest, even tho I allowed the guest checkout in the woocommerce settings.

Comment: Heyja, There is probably nothing wrong with the code. It works fine as logged in user. Its just the function add_to_cart from WooCommerce thats seems to create a problem after adding an item to cart when there is no logged in user.

Comment: Wow yea, it works! Thank you very much, youre my man! Can you explain whats going on?

Comment: Oh i Figured that my admin area doesnt work anymore when i add your code. HTTP 500 Error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initiate Woocommerce User session when it's not logged in. So you will use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'force_non_logged_user_wc_session' );
function force_non_logged_user_wc_session(){ 
    if( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() )
       return;

    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) 
       WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true ); 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: YES! Thank you very much. Your reply will probably help a few people since i saw a lot of similar questions in the net. It also fixed the http 500 error. awesome

Comment: @xDrago I have marked as duplicate the [linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871936/woocommerce-wc-cart-add-to-cart-is-not-working-for-visitors-but-works-for) in your question … This will help people to find out this thread easily.

Comment: Part of me wants to question why WC originally made it like this, but a bigger part of me is just relieved to have a fix. :) Thank you.