# Cart empty after add to cart method

Tags: session, cookies, woocommerce, cart

I am working on one functionality for WC variable product. It will be ticket with various "levels", for each level another price. User should pick number of tickets he wants, after that form should be created in which he can add Name, Address and Ticket Level for each ticket(row). All this data should be after that sent to cart and saved to order.

**EDIT 2**

Hello guys, again.

I spent some more time on this and went further.

I almost did what i wanted:

1. User can choose number of tickets
2. User can fill additional info for each ticket (name, address, bio, ticket level)
3. All of these rows will be added to cart
4. All of these data are displayed in cart and checkout
5. All of these data will be send to order/email

Now i found problem (sure, there are maybe more problems). But, i was doing it the whole time as logged user in same windows of browser. 
After that i realized that when i am using inkognito mode, or another browser with no session or cookies stored for this site, after adding items to cart, cart is empty.

When i tried to first add some other item that is using regular WC add to cart button it worked, after that i can add my tickets without problem.

But when i try to add tickets first, cart is empty. In my main browser as logged user i have no problem.

I did some research on this, but i was just trying. I dont really understand the problem so i am wasting time again.

If someone can help me or guide me towards solution i would be glad.

Thank you for your time.

Below is code from my plugin:

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    if ( ! class_exists( 'UberMike' ) ) {

        class UberMike{
            private static $farba_vlastnost = 'attribute_pa_level-bezca';
            private static $attributes_values = array();

            public function __construct() {
                self::$farba_vlastnost = self::$farba_vlastnost;
                self::$attributes_values = self::$attributes_values;
                // called only after woocommerce has finished loading
                add_action( 'woocommerce_init', array( &$this, 'woocommerce_loaded' ) );
                // called after all plugins have loaded
                add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( &$this, 'plugins_loaded' ) );
                //enqueue scripts and css style
                add_action("wp_loaded", array( &$this, "enqueue_scripts") );
                //add custom actions
                //remove WC action completely
                add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function () {
                    remove_action('woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30);
                }, -1000);
                //add custom add to cart
                add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', array( $this, 'add_to_cart'), 30 );
                //create collapsible section input number and button
                add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', array( $this, 'createCollapsibleSection') );
                //hide collapsible section in header
                add_action('wp_footer', array( $this, 'collapsibleSectionHeader') );
                //boot session
                // add_action('wp_head', array( $this, 'hook_cookie') );
                add_action('wp_head', array( $this, 'boot_session') );
                //display meta data to each item in cart anch checkout
                add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', array( $this, 'ubermike_render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout'), 20, 2 );
                //display grouped custom fields in checkout and order notes
                add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', array( $this, 'my_custom_checkout_field') );
                add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $this, 'my_custom_checkout_field') );
                //display fields in order and email
                add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', array( $this, 'save_custom_order_item_meta_data'), 10, 4 );
            }
            /**
         * Take care of anything that needs woocommerce to be loaded.
         * For instance, if you need access to the $woocommerce global
         */
            public function woocommerce_loaded() {
                // ...
            }
            /**
             * Take care of anything that needs all plugins to be loaded
             */
            public function plugins_loaded() {
                // ...
            }
            //enqueue JS scripts and CSS style
            public function enqueue_scripts() {
                wp_register_style( 'ubermike_css', plugins_url('assets/ubermike.css', __FILE__) );
                wp_enqueue_style('ubermike_css');

                wp_register_script( 'ubermike_js', plugins_url('assets/ubermike.js',__FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ));
                wp_enqueue_script('ubermike_js');
            }

            //add to cart replacement
            public function add_to_cart($allsets){
                global $product, $post, $woocommerce;

                //check product category
                $is_ticket = false;
                $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                foreach ($terms as $t){
                    if ($t->slug=='ticket'){
                        $is_ticket = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //if the category is other than ticket, basic WC single variable product will be displayed on frontend
                if (!method_exists($product,'get_variation_attributes') || !$is_ticket) {
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );

                    wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php', array(
                        'available_variations'  => $product->get_available_variations(),
                        'attributes'            => $product->get_variation_attributes(),
                        'selected_attributes'   => $product->get_default_attributes()
                        ) );
                    return;
                }

                //get product variations
                $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
                //storing variables of product and each variation of this product
                //product ID and quantity (default 1 piece for row)
                $custom_product_id = $product->get_id();
                $custom_product_quantity = 1;
                //storing variations data to variables with index
                $index_n = 1;
                ?>
                <div id="hidden-variables-container">
                <?php
                foreach($variations as $var) {
                    $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($var['variation_id']);
                    //here i used ->id before
                    // $somevar = $this->_fillAttributeValues($product, $product_variation->get_id());
                    $this->_fillAttributeValues($product, $product_variation->id);
                    //variation attribute name json encode
                    $attr_text[$index_n] = json_encode($var['attributes']);
                    //variation name to display in frontend
                    $variation_name_to_display[$index_n] = self::_getAttributeValue($var['attributes']);
                    //variation attribute name json encode htmlspecialchars
                    $variation_name_full[$index_n] = htmlspecialchars($attr_text[$index_n]);
                    //variation id
                    $variation_id[$index_n] = $var['variation_id'];

                    ?>
                        <!-- Variables to frontend for JS use -->
                        <div class="hidden-variable <?php echo $index_n; ?>">
                        <span class="um_variation_name_frontend <?php echo $index_n; ?>"><?php echo $variation_name_to_display[$index_n]; ?></span>
                        <span class="um_variation_attribute_name <?php echo $index_n; ?>"><?php echo  $variation_name_full[$index_n]; ?></span>
                        <span class="um_variation_id <?php echo $index_n; ?>"><?php echo  $variation_id[$index_n];?></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $index_n++;
                }
                ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }

            //get values of attributes
            private function _getAttributeValue($get_attributes){
                $text = '';
                foreach ($get_attributes as $name=>$attribute){
                    if ($name==self::$farba_vlastnost){
                        if (isset(self::$attributes_values['pa_level-bezca'][$attribute])) $text = self::$attributes_values['pa_level-bezca'][$attribute];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (empty($text)){
                    $text = [];
                    foreach ($get_attributes as $name=>$attribute){
                        if (isset(self::$attributes_values[substr($name, strlen('attribute_'))][$attribute])) $text[] = self::$attributes_values[substr($name, strlen('attribute_'))][$attribute];
                    }
                    $text = join(', ', $text);
                }
                return $text;
            }

            //fill attribute values to display name in frontend
            private function _fillAttributeValues($product, $product_variation_id){
                $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute){
                    if ($attribute['is_taxonomy']){
                        $post_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_variation_id, $attribute[ 'name' ] );
                        foreach ( $post_terms as $term ) {
                            self::$attributes_values[$term->taxonomy][$term->slug] = esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        function createCollapsibleSection(){
            global $product, $post, $woocommerce;
            //check if product term is ticket
            $is_ticket = false;
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
            foreach ($terms as $t){
                if ($t->slug=='ticket'){
                    $is_textil = true;
                } else{
                }
            }
            ?>

            <!-- Input type number for JS created fields -->
            <div class="quantity">
                <label class="tickets-quantity" for="number-of-tickets">Vyberte počet lístkov</label>
                <input type="number" id="number-of-tickets" class="" step="1" min="1" max="" name="number-of-tickets" value="1" title="Počet" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
            </div>
            <!-- This span opens hidden modal with input rows -->
            <span class="open-modal"> Vyplniť údaje  </span>
                <?php
            }

            function collapsibleSectionHeader(){
                global $product, $post, $woocommerce;
                ?>
                            <!-- Form with input fields and select for variation -->
                            <div id="clone-wrapper-bigbranding" class="collapsible-wrapper-bigbranding hidenx">
                                <div class="uber-modal">
                                <span class="close-modal">Zatvoriť</span>
                                <form id="form-motherboard" action="#" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php $product->id; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ubermike" value="1">
                                <input class="do-kosika" type="submit" name="submit" value="Pridať do košíka" />
                                <?php
                                        if (isset($_POST['ubermike'])){
                                            $product_id = absint($_POST['product_id']);
                                            // This loops through rows and adds products to cart
                                            $cnt = count($_POST['ticketLevel']);
                                            $quantity_total = 0;

                                                for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
                                                        $cats = explode("|", $_POST['ticketLevel'][$i]);
                                                        $selected_val = $cats[0]; // cat_id
                                                        $selected_level = $cats[1]; // cat_name
                                                        $customer_name = $_POST['name'][$i];
                                                        $customer_address = $_POST['address'][$i];
                                                        $customer_bio = $_POST['bio'][$i];
                                                        $custom_data = array(); // Initializing

                                                        $custom_data['custom_data']['name'] = array(
                                                                'label' => 'Meno',
                                                                'value' => $customer_name
                                                        );
                                                        $custom_data['custom_data']['address'] = array(
                                                                'label' => 'Adresa',
                                                                'value' => $customer_address
                                                        );
                                                        $custom_data['custom_data']['bio'] = array(
                                                                'label' => 'Bio',
                                                                'value' => $customer_bio
                                                        );
                                                        $custom_data['custom_data']['level'] = array(
                                                                'label' => 'Level',
                                                                'value' => $selected_level
                                                        );

                                                        $quantity = 1;

                                                        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $selected_val, array(), $custom_data );

                                                        do_action( 'woocommerce_set_cart_cookies', TRUE );

                                                        $quantity_total += $quantity;

                                                }

                                                if ($quantity_total) wc_add_to_cart_message( array( $product_id => $quantity_total ), true );
                                        }
                                 ?>
                                </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?
            }

            function ubermike_render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item ){
                    $custom_items = array();

                    if( !empty( $cart_data ) )
                            $custom_items = $cart_data;

                    if( isset( $cart_item['custom_data'] ) ) {
                            foreach( $cart_item['custom_data'] as $key => $custom_data ){
                                    if( $key != 'key' ){
                                            $custom_items[] = array(
                                                    'name' => $custom_data['label'],
                                                    'value' => $custom_data['value'],
                                            );
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    return $custom_items;
            }

            function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
                    global $woocommerce;

                    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Údaje objednávky') . '</h2>';
                    $indexing = 1;
                    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                            if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']) ) {

                                echo '<div class="uber-ticket-wrapper">';
                                echo '<div class="uber-ticket">Ticket ' . $indexing . ' </div>';
                                    foreach( $cart_item['custom_data'] as $key => $custom_data ){
                                            if( $key != 'key' ){
                                                            echo $custom_data['label'];
                                                            echo("<br>");
                                                            echo $custom_data['value'];
                                                            echo("<br>");
                                            }
                                    }
                                    echo "</div>";
                                    $indexing++;
                            }
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
            }

            // Save cart item custom data as order item meta data and display it everywhere in Orders and email notifications
            function save_custom_order_item_meta_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
                if (isset($values['custom_data'])) {
                    foreach( $values['custom_data'] as $key => $custom_data ){
                            if( $key != 'key' ){
                                $item->update_meta_data( $custom_data['label'], $custom_data['value'] );
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

            function boot_session() {
                session_start();
            }
        }
        //instantiate plugin class and add it to the set of globals
        $GLOBALS['ubermike'] = new UberMike();
    }
}
```

Here is picture that shows single-product and then form in modal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53422060/12897376

You need to initiate Woocommerce User session when it's not logged in. So you will use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'force_non_logged_user_wc_session' );
function force_non_logged_user_wc_session(){ 
    if( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() )
       return;

    if ( ! WC()->session->has_session() ) 
       WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true ); 
}
```

Many thanks.